# I want to have a 2D list with value and color attributes in Python

Tags: python

I have a matrix like this:

```
 mat = [[1,2,4,5], [2,3,4,1], [4,1,1,2], [1,1,1,0]]
```

each cell has initially `white` color associated with it. When the cell gets visited it's color changes to `black`.

Now I don't know how to initialize this kind of matrix in Python. Please help me to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the cell gets visited"?

Comment: I want to implement floodfill algorithm. But here the coloring will be done on the basis of the difference of the values of two adjacent cells.

Comment: I'd create a second matrix with all the colors. That makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass `int` and add a `color` attribute:

```
class Cell(int):
    def __init__(self, value, color='white'):
        super().__init__(value)
        self.color = color

mat = [[1,2,4,5], [2,3,4,1], [4,1,1,2], [1,1,1,0]]
mat = [[Cell(i) for i in l] for l in mat]
```

Now you can access the color using the cell's `color` attribute:

```
mat[y][x].color = 'black'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to store color names and integers in one array, you can do something like the following:

```py
mat = [[[1, "white"], [2, "white"], [4, "white"], [5, "white"]],
       [[2, "white"], [3, "white"], [4, "white"], [1, "white"]],
       [[4, "white"], [1, "white"], [1, "white"], [2, "white"]],
       [[1, "white"], [1, "white"], [1, "white"], [0, "white"]]]
```

Then you access an integer with `mat[i][j][0]` and its color with `mat[i][j][1]`.

I, however, would use two separate arrays: `mat[i][j]` and `color[i][j]`.

Comment: Okay let me try with your two separate array technique. I think it will be a better way to do it.